# How to integrate Firebase Flashlight in my application

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, firebase

I am trying to integrate [Firebase Flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) with ElasticSearch in my Node.js application in order to make search operations on my Firebase collections. I want to do this in `api.js` where to define my search routes (e.g:  `myhost: myport/ search/mycollection/:key`).

The problem is that that `myport` is different that the one on which ElasticSearch is running (which is 9200).

I want on route: `myhost: myport/whatever` to run my app, and on route  `myhost: myport/ search/mycollection/:key` to run the search that is now available at `myhost:9200`.

How can I integrate them in Express?

When I config ElasticSearch, I use:

```
var config = {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 9200,
      log: 'trace'
};
var esc = new ElasticSearch.Client(config);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal that Elastic Search will run on a different port than your Express application. In fact, you can *not* have two servers running on the same port.

Flashlight is more like a different app, which you need to run on your server. Using `npm start` or `npm monitor` you can start the Flashlight process after setting up the configuration file. Flashlight will take care to bring you the data from Firebase in Elastic Search.

To interact with Elastic Search, you simply have to use the Node module. You already do that. Elastic Search will run on port `9200`, as you mentioned, while the Express app will run on a different port (e.g. `3000`).

Inspired from Flashlight, I created [**Elasticfire**](https://github.com/Bloggify/elasticfire) which has a few features which Flashlight doesn't have (e.g. joins), and can be used as a library in your app.

```
const ElasticFire = require("elasticfire");

// Initialize the ElasticFire instance
let ef = new ElasticFire({

    // Set the Firebase configuration
    firebase: {
        apiKey: "AI...BY",
        authDomain: "em...d.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://em...d.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: "em...d.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "95...36"
    }

    // Firebase paths and how to index them in Elasticsearch
  , paths: [
       {
           // Firebase path
           path : "articles"

           // Elasticsearch index and type
         , index: "articles"
         , type : "article"

           // Optional joined fields
         , joins: [
               // The `author` is a field from the article
               // which points to the `users` collection.
               {
                   path: "users"
                 , name: "author"
               }

               // If we have an array of comment ids, pointing
               // to another collection, then they will be joined too
             , {
                   path: "comments"
                 , name: "comments"
               }
           ]

           // Filter out some data
         , filter: (data, snap) => snap.key !== "_id"
       }
    ]
});

// Listen for the events emitted by
// the ElasticFire instanceand output some data
ef.on("error", err => {
    console.error(err);
}).on("index_created", name => {
    console.log(`${name} created`);
}).on("index_updated", name => {
    console.log(`${name} updated`);
}).on("index_deleted", name => {
    console.log(`${name} deleted`);
});
```